# Shell de Python se queda en blanco

Tags: python, shell

mi Python funcionaba perfecto. De un día a otro intenté correr un programa con el que hago scrap y comenzó a darme el siguiente error: "No module named irllib" Observen que escribo irllib (con i). Mi programa no ha sido modificado y ninguna línea dice 'irl' (están con urllib). 
Luego Python dejó de funcionar. Cuando lo corro desde IDLE sólo muestra la pantalla del shell en blanco como aparece en esta imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
Ni siquiera se puede cerrar el programa. Debo entrar a administrador de tareas y liquidar el proceso desde ahí.
Lo he intentado correr desde Atom y de nada sirve.
En los días previos no he instalado nada nuevo en mi máquina.

He hecho lo siguiente:
1) Desinstalé y volví a instalar Python. Sin efecto.
2) Desinstalé Atom, en caso de que algún script cause un error. Sin efecto.
3) He escaneado mi máquina utilizando Kaspersky en modo a prueba de fallas de windows considerando que lo del 'irllib' es muy sospechoso. Sin virus. Sin embargo, el online scanner de Eset nod32 se quedaba en blanco también.
4) También revisé el módulo urllib en la librería y no hay ningún 'irllib' por ninguna parte.
Por favor, AYÚDENME!
¿De qué se trata este problema y cómo lo resuelvo?

Datos del sistema: 
minilaptop con Windows 7 starter (SP1) 32 bits, RAM(1G). 
Python 3.8.1. Está registrado el PATH en las variables del sistema.

Saludos a todos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, aKratos, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Te pasa solo con ese script o con cualquiera? ¿Puedes ejecutar el interprete interactivo desde una terminal?

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, me pasa con todos los scripts que he desarrollado. Al dispararse el Shell se queda en blanco. Si corro desde cmd arroja el error 'irllib' y aun cuando en otro script no uso 'urllib' también me da el mismo error.

Comment: Si cargo solo python desde el cmd sí carga. Si escribo 1+1 sí funciona, devuelve 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví mi problema con el shell de Python. Cuando reinstalé python para intentar solucionar el problema, python se instaló en 'C:\Archivos de programa' y enrutamiento previo estaba en 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs ...' Opté por eliminar la primera carpeta en Archivos de programas (simplemente la borré, no desinstalé python nuevamente) y dejé solo la que estaba en AppData. Eso resolvió mi problema con el Shell.

El problema con 'irllib' se debía a un script de prueba con nombre 'urllib.py' que tenía en mi carpeta de proyectos, entonces al correr el programa python daba preferencia a ese archivo y estaba malo (lo había creado yo mismo pero no tenía nada que ver con el módulo urllib). Eliminé este archivo y problema resuelto.